# React Router Dom Prevent Prompt When Params Change

Tags: reactjs, redux, prompt, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am building a React Redux application and I am using `<Prompt/>` from `react-router-dom` to prevent a user from navigating away from a page when a specific icon is being rendered on the page.

It works fine except for when the params in the `url` change and then it fires the `<Prompt/>` when I don't want it to fire because I haven't actually tried to navigate anywhere. My url looks like:

`http://localhost:8080/#/path/im/on?ids=1%2C24&from=1512518400000&searchRequest=e0007&to=1512604799000`

When the `ids` in the `url` become successful, they are removed from the `url` but `<Prompt/>` is still fired.

Is there any way I can prevent `<Prompt/>` from firing when the `url` `params` change and the first part of the `url` stays the same? i.e. `http://localhost:8080/#/path/im/on`

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: I'm afraid not 

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still relevant to you but you can do the following:

'message' prop in the Prompt component can either be a string or a function that returns a string or boolean.

```
<Prompt
     message={(location) => {
       return location.pathname.startsWith("your url")
         ? true
         : `Are you sure you want to go to ${location.pathname}?`
     }}
/>
```

if a function is passed to message prop then it will be called with the next location and action the user is attempting to navigate to. Return a string to show a prompt to the user or true to allow the transition.

here is the documentation link: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Prompt.md

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @siddhartha bimanathi unfortunately I've moved on from that codebase and will never encounter it again so I cant test your suggestion.